# At each form submit how does one put a new data item into local storage?

Tags: javascript, object, merge, local-storage, key-value-store

I want that every time a form is submitted, a new equipment with the equipment number as KEY is created in the local storage.

E.g.

> LocalStorage:

| Key: | Value: |
| --- | --- |
| E123456789 | ordernumber: 456, date: 05.11.2022 |
| E987654321 | ordernumber :654, date: 05.11.2022 |

This is my code:

```js
class Equipment {
  constructor(
    equipmentnumber,
    ordernumber,
    date
  ) {
    this.equipmentnumber = equipmentnumber;
    this.ordernumber = ordernumber;
    this.date = date;
  }
}

function addProcess() {
  let equipment = new Equipment(
    equipmentnumber.value,
    ordernumber.value,
    date.value
  );
  localStorage.setItem('equipment', JSON.stringify(equipment));
}
```

And this is what I get:

> LocalStorage:

| Key: | Value: |
| --- | --- |
| Equipment | equipmentnumber: 123, ordernumber: 456, date: 05.11.2022 |

Comment: The first argument to [`setItem`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) is the key. You’re setting the key `"equipment"`, literally. Have you tried setting the key `equipmentnumber.value`? The value (i.e. the second argument to `setItem`), then, should just be `JSON.stringify({ ordernumber: ordernumber.value, date: date.value })`. You could, however, define this object as the return value of the [`toJSON`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description) method in `class Equipment`.

Comment: @silvermir ... Regarding the so far provided approaches / solutions are there any questions left?

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `setItem` is the key of the pair that you are trying to save. In your case you are passing `equipment` as a key so that explains your result. One of the following solutions might be what you are looking for.

---

Format the key using a template literal according to the example you gave us, ex. `E123456789`.

```
localStorage.setItem(`E${equipment.equipmentnumber}`, JSON.stringify({ordernumber: equipment.ordernumber, date: equipment.date}))
```

Or pass only the `equipmentnumber` as the key:

```
localStorage.setItem(equipment.equipmentnumber, JSON.stringify({ordernumber: equipment.ordernumber, date: equipment.date}))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the already provided solution one could think about a `class` free (such an abstraction is really not needed) approach where one does both, creating the correct current equipment-data related storage-item which always is an object with e single key (the OP's `equipmentnumber`  value from the OP's currently submitted form data) e.g. ...

```
{
  E123456789: {
    ordernumber: '456',
    date: '05.11.2022',
  }, 
}
```

... or ...

```
{
  E987654321: {
    ordernumber: '654',
    date: '05.11.2022',
  }, 
}
```

... and the correct merger of always the parsed current storage-data and the currently submitted equipment-data's related storage item.

For the above two equipment-data examples, where the first object is the currently stored data and the second object is the equipment-item equivalent of the just submitted form-data, the merger of the newly to be stored (updated) equipment-data would be ...

```
{
  E123456789: {
    ordernumber: '456',
    date: '05.11.2022',
  }, 
  E987654321: {
    ordernumber: '654',
    date: '05.11.2022',
  }, 
}
```

Thus, for a generic and/or more easy to maintain approach the OP needs to

- firstly create a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) instance of the currently processed/submitted form ...

  ```
  const formData = new FormData(evt.currentTarget);
  ```
- ... since in a second step it is easier to create/[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) an object from all of the [`formData.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries).

  ```
  const itemData = [...formData.entries()]
    .reduce((result, [key, value]) =>
      Object.assign(result, { [ key ]: value }), {}
    );
  ```
- The related current (and to be merged/stored) equipment-data object then most easily is created by an immediately invoked [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which allows for the most generic `equipmentnumber` specific object creation by using the [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) in combination with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

  ```
  const currentEquipmentData = (({ equipmentnumber, ...data }) => ({
    [ equipmentnumber ]: { ... data }
  }))(itemData);
  ```
- The parsed currently stored equipment-data ...

  ```
  const storedEquipmentData = JSON
    .parse(
      localStorage.getItem('equipment-data') ?? null
    ) ?? {};
  ```
- ... then has to be merged (e.g. again by spread syntax) before ...

  ```
  const mergedEquipmentData = {
    ...storedEquipmentData,
    ...currentEquipmentData,
  };
  ```
- ... the such updated equipment-data is going to be stored again ...

  ```
  localStorage.setItem(
    'equipment-data',
    JSON.stringify(mergedEquipmentData),
  );
  ```

```js
function handleEquipmentItemStorage(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData(evt.currentTarget);

  const itemData = [...formData.entries()]
    .reduce((result, [key, value]) =>
      Object.assign(result, { [ key ]: value }), {}
    );

  const currentEquipmentData = (({ equipmentnumber, ...data }) => ({
    [ equipmentnumber ]: { ... data }
  }))(itemData);

  const storedEquipmentData = JSON
    .parse(
      mock.localStorage.getItem('equipment-data') ?? null
    ) ?? {};

  const mergedEquipmentData = {
    ...storedEquipmentData,
    ...currentEquipmentData,
  };
  // delete an empty key.
  Reflect.deleteProperty(mergedEquipmentData, '');

  if (Object.keys(mergedEquipmentData).length >= 1) {

    mock.localStorage.setItem(
      'equipment-data',
      JSON.stringify(mergedEquipmentData),
    );
  }

  console.log({
    itemData,

    currentEquipmentData:
      structuredClone?.(currentEquipmentData) || currentEquipmentData,

    storedEquipmentData:
      structuredClone?.(storedEquipmentData) || storedEquipmentData,

    mergedEquipmentData:
      structuredClone?.(mergedEquipmentData) || mergedEquipmentData,
  });

  return false;
}

function main() {
  document
    .querySelector('form')
    .addEventListener('submit', handleEquipmentItemStorage);
}
main();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
form { width: 28%; }
form input { display: block; width: 100%; margin: 4px 0; }
form button { margin: 8px 0; }
.as-console-wrapper {
  left: auto!important;
  max-height: unset!important;
  height: 100%;
  width: 69%;
}
```

```html
<script>
  // mock for the SO specific stack snippet
  // due to the policies and environment are
  // not allowing an original storage access.
  const mock = {
    localStorage: (function () {

      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map
      const storage = new Map;

      function key(int) {
        return [
          ...storage.keys()
        ][parseInt(int, 10)];
      }

      function setItem(key, value) {
        return storage.set(String(key), String(value));
      }
      function getItem(key) {
        return storage.get(String(key));
      }

      function removeItem(key) {
        return storage.delete(String(key));
      }

      function clear() {
        return storage.clear();
      }

      return {
        get length() {
          return storage.size;
        },
        key,
        getItem,
        setItem,
        removeItem,
        clear,      
      };

    }()),
  }
</script>

<form action="/" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="equipmentnumber" placeholder="equipment number" />
  <input type="number" name="ordernumber" min="400" max="600" step="1" placeholder="order number" />
  <input type="date" name="date"/>

  <button type="submit">submit equipment item</button>
</form>

<button onclick="console.clear()">clear console</button>
```